# Minimize all windows with keyboard shortcut in Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-3

I have Debian 9 with GNOME 3.22.2.
I want minimize all windows with `super+D` shortcut keyboard. This command working in Ubuntu 18.04 but not working in Debian. I wanted to add keyboard shortcut to custom shortcut, but i did not know the command to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide all normal windows inactive by default in Debian 9, I found it in keyboard shortcut  list in navigation section and set `Super+D` shortcut.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.